# what emmet shortcut to edit several elements at once

Tags: html, css, emmet

I've written my HTML in bootstrap 4 using the breakpoint of `col-sm` for everything. I want to edit the entire document to `col-lg`. Which emmet shortcut can I use to edit all at once to change everything instead of manually moving to each line to change every letter from `col-sm` to `col-lg`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with emmet. Use your text editor's find and replace functionality

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Thanks. But using the find functionality I'd still need to manually move to each `col-sm` and edit all of them manually. I have a lot of them. I want to edit all at once instead of searching and editing each one individually, Please, is this clear

Comment: Which editor do you use to change the html? What @EmanuelVintilă proposes is not to do it one at the time, but using your editor to change them all at once. For instance using VSCODE, you can do it like described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_find-and-replace

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code(not sure that this is feature of VS code or in-built emmet in VS code then you can put multiple cursors by holding **alt** key and then clicking on places where you want cursor.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. Although it works, how can I used the find functionality together with your method to make it more robust. I had to keep on searching for them and go back to point the cursor at each section. I am using VScode